# Webpack2- Using file-loader loaded URLs of dependency project

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

I have a library that is packaged using webpack. I've used file-loader with below config:

```
    {
    //file-loader config of library
    test: /\.(tsv|json)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
}
```

When a webpack build is run, the files are stored in dist/ folder as expected.
All my references to these files does work fine if I host the dist folder of library.

I use the above library in other project(also a webpack proj) as a dependency using npm.

To access components of lib in the project, I use the ProviderPlugin as:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
myCustomLib: '<myLibName>'
})
```

With this setup I can access the library classes(ES6) as **myCustomLib.LibraryClassName** with no issues.

But the project fails loading URL's configured in library as the project's file loader config is different:

```
      {
          //file-loader config of project using the library
          test: /\.(tsv)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
      }
```

All my library files are getting placed in dist/assets/ but my library code expects it to be from dist/. How do I tweak the project config to handle this case. Or have I taken a totally wrong approach. Is there something I should correct